# Relation between MTTF (Mean Time to Failure) and FIT (Failure in time) in computer architecture

Tags: computer-architecture

I have a doubt regarding relation between MTTF (Mean Time to Failure) and FIT (Failure in time). Is it FIT = 1/(MTTF1 + MTTF2 + ...) or FIT = 1/MTTF1 + 1/MTTF2 + ... ?